# Spring @Transactional. How does it really work?

Tags: java, hibernate, spring-mvc

We are using Spring and Hibernate in our project. We are using Spring transactional annotations and we understand what it does, but we still have some doubts regarding rollbacks.

Let's say we have the following code.

```
@Transactional
@Service
public class PersonServiceImpl implements PersonService {

    @Autowired
    private PersonDao personDao;

    @Autowired
    private AnotherService anotherService;

    @Override
    public void doSomething() throws Exception {
        Person person = new Person();
        person.setName("John");
        personDao.insert(person);
        person.setName("Megan");

        //What happens if the following call fails and throws and exception.
        personDao.update(person);

        // What happens if this other service's call fails?
        anotherService.doSomethingElse();
    }

}
```

If either the update or the other service's call fails, what would happen to the insert? Would there be a rollback and the insert would never be executed? Or would the insert still persist in the DB? Do I need to declare the following command in each method for the rollback to be executed.

```
@Transactional(rollbackFor= Exception.class)
```

If that is the case, what happens if my service call throws the exception? Would it still works? Thanks for the help. I would really liked to understand the way rollbacks are executed inside a service call.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

By default if the exception is checked (extends Exception), the rollback won't happen - the transaction will be committed. Otherwise (if defaults were changed or we're talking about unchecked exceptions), the transaction is rolled back and INSERT/UPDATE statements don't persist anything. BTW, this is described in the JavaDocs to the rollbackFor attribute ;)

If the exception is eventually thrown from your Transactional method it doesn't matter where that exception originated.

If you're not sure about the behaviour, you can always debug Spring's `HibernateTransactionManager` and its superclasses.

Comment: Ok, so from the docs I read that only if rollbackFor is present, a rollback will occur with checked exceptions. So, in the example given above, this would mean that no rollback would occur, because I was missing the rollbackFor configuration. Now, one last thing. Ff the call that fails is that of the other service, and inside it I also declared the rollbackFor attribute, would we get an issue? Or would it simply just execute the rollback as intended?